# Correct way to remove temp file after reponse has been sent

Tags: node.js, express, httpresponse

I have a simple Express 4 based API that outputs an MP3 file that was generated based on some provided parameters. However, I seem to be unable to delete this temporary MP3 file after the response has been sent out.

What I have:

```
app.get('/endpoint', function(request, response) {

  // Distill parameters from request and create tempFileMp3  

  var stat = Fs.statSync(tempFileMp3);

  response.writeHead(status, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    'Content-Length': stat.size
  });

  stream = Fs.createReadStream(tempFileMp3);
  stream.pipe(response);
});
```

At first I was hoping that I would be able to delete the `tempFileMp3` in a `stream` event, either the `end` or `finish` events:

```
stream
  .on('end', function() {
    Fs.unlinkSync(tempFileMp3);
  })
  .on('close', function() {
    Fs.unlinkSync(tempFileMp3);
  })
;
```

But neither the `end` nor `close` events are fired.

How can I delete the temporary MP3 file after the response has been sent?

Comment: Try `stream.on('finish', function () { Fs.unlinkSync(tempFileMp3); });` ?
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

Comment: @SwarajGiri Actually tried that. Forgot to mention, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try capture response finish:

```
res.on('finish', function() {
  // remove temp files
});

res.on('error', function() {
  // remove temp files
});
```

Comment: The `response.finish` event seems to be called sporadically, i.e. sometimes it is and sometimes it's not. Is there any documentation on these events?